# What is the purpose of the scale argument in functions such as setYLabelsColor()?

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

In the achartengine library, the class [XYMultipleSeriesRenderer](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/index.html?help-doc.html) which has two functions:

```
public void setXLabelsColor(int color)

public void setYLabelsColor(int scale, int color)
```

`setXLabelsColor()` intuitively makes sense since one only needs to pass in the color, but for the longest time I could not figure out what the 'scale' argument is for `setYLabelsColor` did.  The docs says, it is "renderer scale", but it is not apparently clear what values scale could be.  After messing around with the inputs, I finally got the function to work with a 'scale' value of 0.  This does not make intuitive sense to me.  I thought that a scale value of 1 would mean the chart keeps its scale.  Why does a value of 0 work, whereas a default scale value of 1 doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at below image. There are two lines in there, scaled in a separate way, the "Air temperature" on the left having scale = 0 and the "Sunshine hours" on the right having scale = 1.
[image: pic]
<sub>(source: [achartengine.org](http://www.achartengine.org/dimages/multiple_axis_cubic_line.png))</sub>

Comment: dear Dan i'm facing a problem with scaling in my Barcharts,i have a huge number for y series label(hard to read) and i want it to change to 0.000001 scale,but setting scale doesn't change the scale and i don't want to divide my data with this scale,is there any way to set scale just for y label?

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question describing exactly what the issue is. I think you misunderstand the concept of scale in AChartEngine.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that scale is meant to refer to which series that you are editing. In a multipleXYseriesrenderer, the scale number refers to the "nth" series you entered. For example, if you only have 1 series, then editing scale "0" will edit only that series. This is what my understanding is, although I cannot say for certain. IT seems that the documentation could certainly use some cleaning up.